# How to determine disc usage of a subset of a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to generate a table that groups disc size on a feature based on a filter. For example, this is the kind of query I'd expect to use:

```
select trip,pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('cav_wsu')) as size from wsu where time between 0 and 3600 group by trip;
```

Which would generate something like this:

```
        trip          |    size 
----------------------+-------------
 1000                 | 120 kB      
 1001                 | 256 kB      
 1002                 | 111 kB      
 1003                 | 342 kB
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pg_column_size`:

```
select trip, pg_size_pretty(pg_column_size(wsu)::bigint) as size
from wsu
where time between 0 and 3600
group by trip;
```

Note that this function does not include the space used by indexes and TOAST files. PostgreSQL does not seem to provide (that I know of) a value for that, however you can derive it, as an average, from the ratios of table size to total size, and row size to table size:

```
select trip, pg_size_pretty(pg_column_size(wsu)::bigint) as size,
       pg_size_pretty((pg_column_size(wsu)::float / pg_relation_size('wsu') * pg_total_relation_size('wsu'))::bigint) as total_size
from wsu
where time between 0 and 3600
group by trip;
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one works, but I can't get the second one to work. Also, I'm getting that every single entry = 4 bytes. I expected them to be bigger. When I filter and then export to csv (\g example.csv), the file sizes are much larger (~250kb). Any idea why?

Comment: Oh, I see. This is calculating the size of one column. I was hoping to calculate the size of all columns. Is there any way to do this besides pg_column_size(column1)+pg_column_size(column2)...etc?

Comment: Oops, forgot to tag you @Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister

Comment: @jarch I wonder how is it that you're getting the size of a column instead of the size of the table? Perhaps you have a column with the same name as your table? (e.g. wsu.wsu) If that is the case, then set an alias for the table (e.g. `FROM wsu AS w`, then in the select list `pg_size_pretty(pg_column_size(w)::bigint) as size`. Then, for the second one, I had a bug and I just fixed it (`d` instead of `wsu`)